# медиа запросы вопрос

Tags: css, media-queries

Подскажите пожалуйста ребята.Вопрос такой,есть 2 картинки, однa должна отображаться при разрешении экрана 768px, a когда экран становится 320px, то должна появиться другая картинка взамен той что на 768px, пробовал реализовать почему то не получилось...

```
 @media all and (max-width: 320px) {
    .header__banner__img {
        display: none;
    }
};


@media all and (min-width: 320px) {
    .header__banner__img2 {
        display: none;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо медиа запросов так же можно использовать тег `picture`

```html
<picture>
 <source srcset="https://placeholdit.co//i/320x200" media="(max-width: 768px)">
 <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/600x300">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно не использовать другие классы, изменять в самом `@media`

```css
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
    .header__banner__img {
         content: url('http://via.placeholder.com/140x100')
    }
};

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .header__banner__img {
        content: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Change pictures size after 320px</h2>

<div class="example">
<img class="header__banner__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image" />
</div>

<p> After this viewport changes to be 320px you see different picture</p>
```